# Ban the "network" and "networking" tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging

I would like to suggest banning the [network](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network) and [networking](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) tags.

Any question we ask on this site is by definition a network question.  As such, these tags wind up being a magnet for off-topic questions.  For instance, consider some recent questions closed with this tag:

- https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13267/context-aware-multimedia
- https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13170/expected-no-of-retransmissions
- https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13207/how-to-diagnose-computer-dropping-network-connectivity-when-more-computers-join
- https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13078/newbie-what-is-designing-network-connectors
- https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13068/cannot-enable-internet-sharing

In all, I think we are better off without the tags.  Unless someone voices a reasonable concern below, we will delete the [network](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network) and [networking](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) tags.

Comment: We're better off without it.  There isn't even a good way to write an excerpt for the network tag.

Comment: And also, if it's not related to the Network, how come the question is on Network Engineering...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hate that I had to manually edit over 100 questions to do this, but I am just over 2/3rds done.  We started with around 200 [network](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network) questions, and we're now down to about 60.

**Update 1**:

Thanks to Ryan Foley for helping out with the 60 remaining questions

**Update 2**:

I deleted a bunch of  [networking](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) tags over the weekend, but a moderator will need to delete them from the remaining closed and migrated questions.  I flagged for a moderator to do so but they didn't seem to get the point of my flag.  I just checked and we already have two new posts tagged [networking](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking).

Mods, please delete the [networking](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) tags.  Perhaps blacklisting is warranted, if we can limit it to blacklisting tags.

Comment: That explains the sudden surge of old posts being bumped ;)  Looks like @Ryan Foley took care of the rest.  Thanks Mike and Ryan for taking care of the Network Engineering stack exchange!